# Git find out the last commit i pushed

Tags: git

I want to find out the last thing that I pushed, not the last thing i commited, but pushed.

Is there a git command for this?

*Context:*
I want to squash some commits before merging my dev_branch with a master branch but I have been told you can not rebase anything that is already pushed (is this true?).

So i would like to know what was the last commit that I cannot include in this rebase.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you mean the last commit you pushed to the `master` branch then, assuming your remote is `origin`:

```
git rev-parse origin/master
```

This will show you the commit ID of the tip of the `master` branch of the `origin` origin, *as your local repository is currently aware.*  This may mean that the commit is someone else's commit, if someone else pushed commits after you did and you have since `fetch`ed that branch.

```
git show -p origin/master
```

This command will give you information about the commit, including the commit ID, author, log message, and diff to its parent commit(s).

---

One of my favorite Git commands for doing exactly this kind of inspection:

```
git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --graph --decorate --all
```

This will display a nice ASCII-art graph of the commit history, and each commit will show any refs that are targeting it.  This way you can, at a single glance, see branches and merges in history and easily see where `origin/master` is in relation to your own `master`.

Comment: wow thanks cdhowie that last command is awesome, its really useful! 

i should probably ask this in a seperate question but what is considered better

-git rebase -i
-git merge --squash

What i want to do, is merge my dev branch with master, but have my 100+ commmits compressed into say 4. Not 1, as there are probably 4 key points in its history

Comment: If you have pushed your dev branch then squashing it is a bad idea, as others will have been free to branch from your work.  If it's public, don't change it.  If it is not public then `git rebase -i` will let you choose which distinct commits you want to retain in the history and which you want to squash into them.  `git merge --squash` will only give you the opportunity to create one commit, so ultimately it depends on how many commit objects you want.

Answer (score 3):

The correct command to find the commit you could squash against is:

```
git rev-parse @{push}
```

That command will error out if your repository has no commits, or your repository has no remote to push to.

If the result is equal to `git rev-parse HEAD` (which will also fail if your repository has no commits), then you have nothing to squash.

You can get a list of squashable (not-yet-pushed) commits via `git log @{push}..HEAD`.